# Limit AzureAD app access to certain users / groups

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365api, azureportal

I have an Azure app that uses the Graph API to read calendar & mail data on behalf of users in the domain. The app is usually installed by an admin, and gains access to all available users.

Can an admin restrict access to certain users / groups, so that the app will only be able to access them? I looked into [user assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users) but it didn't seem to do anything.

Is there another way?

Comment: Are you going to limit your application to access certain users' information( like read calendar& mail)?

Answer (score 1):

**Is there another way?**

As it is written on [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users#assign-users-and-groups-to-the-app) that in enterprise application we can do it.

**My Test Case:**

When I have tested with enterprise application I came to know that, once you have added member in that application and assign `read calendar & mail data` permission for that application, all the user in that application can access that resource. unfortunately, for individual user it doesn't work currently.

**Note:** You can post your feedback regarding your concern as we have open a thread for user feedback [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/31918). Your feedback cordially
 evaluated.

**Update:** I have forwarded your case to internal support team once they sent me reply I would update my answer if there is any work around.

**Your Work Around Would Be:**

Try to create new role on your application. Like Admin, User on your application manifest file like below:

[image]

You can use [GUID generator](https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx) to create GUID.

Then assign user on that particular role like below:

[image]

On azure  portal side you can do it to restrict user. You could see [RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/deny-assignments) for that.

**On Your Application Inside:**

Once you have configured like above now you would get this claims on your application. Now you can set more custom logic on your code. You could check [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims/)

**Further Escalation:**

For further enhancement you could raise a support ticket on your `azure portal`. See the screen shot below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks got the answer. This actually is an enterprise application using the Graph API, and not a native one.
I tried user assignment but it did not seem to work as I intended.
Can I consult you directly on this matter? We're looking for a solution for quite some time now and can't find any answers online.
Would really appreciate if you or a counterpart can jump on a quick call.
Thanks!

Comment: @DorShemer I was on weekend. Sorry for the delay reply.